# What is the mean value theorem for the Fréchet (total) derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What is the mean value theorem for the Fréchet (total) derivative?  Off the top of my head, it's something like
$$
\|F(x+h)-F(x)\|\leq \sup_{c\in[0,1]} \|F^\prime(x+ch)\|\|h\|
$$
but the double direction of $h$ on the right hand side feels odd to me and I'm not entirely sure what all of the assumptions behind the statement should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The inequality can be proved for any Gateaux-differentiable $F$. This is clear, since you are proving a 1D fact, namely an estimate on the line joining $x$ and $x+h$.

The proof is easy in the special case $F \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$: just consider $t \mapsto F(tx+(1-t)(x+h))$ and apply the MVT. If $F$ is vector-valued, then you need a corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem. You can refer to the book by Ambrosetti and Prodi, *A primer of nonlinear analysis*, Cambridge 1995.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for the result, it's Theorem 1.8 on page 13 of the aforementioned book.